# Input name attribute in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, razor

I am trying to convert the following input name attribute in MVC2 into the equivalent in razor.

```
name="<%=ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(String.Empty)%>.Day"
```

In razor I am using

`name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(String.Empty).Day"`

but it is complaining because it is saying "string' does not contain a definition for 'Day' and no extension method 'Day' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found". The property is a datetime property and the above works in MVC2.

ANy help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(String.Empty)).Day`

notice the `()` around the primary portion of the method call. This tells the parser to only include the elements within those `()` to be compiled. Anything else is ignored. The reason this is necessary is because the `.Day` portion of your snippet looks like a property call to the compiler and is treated as such.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

See whether this works: `@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("Day")`

On other note,what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
name="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(String.Empty) + ".Day")"
```